# How to install specific openjdk version in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: java, java-8, ubuntu-16.04

I have a new Ubuntu server and when I run "sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk", this installed OpenJDK version "1.8.0_312", all good here.

I have one more Ubuntu 16.04 server which already has OpenJDK version "1.8.0_292". How can I change this 1.8.0_292 to "1.8.0_312"?

Comment: If 312 is distributed via Ubuntu, then `apt-get upgrade` (potentially after `apt-get update`) should get you to the latest version. If it doesn't, then check the `apt` sources on the working server (i.e. `/etc/apt/sources.list` and the files in `/etc/apt/source.list.d`) where the updated JDK came from.

Comment: Maybe this can help:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/987748/install-exact-version-of-openjdk

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/). I'm not 100% sure about compatibility with 16.04 specifically, but it shouldn't be a problem.